# colorControlHighlight not working for my button, since I have put background to my button

Tags: android, android-layout

colorControlHighlight not working for my button, since I have put background to my button

my button

```
 <Button
            android:text="OTHERS"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/others_button"
            android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
            android:background="#A4000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

My style item

```
 <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

If there is no background color given to button then it will work

Comment: you can use elevation property in xml for shadow  .

Comment: @Chetan didn't get you

Comment: their is another property in xml called `elevation` for shadow around button , you can use that.

Comment: @Chetan instead of background if i use elevation and the transparent color will it be transparent button

Comment: you can use  both  background and elevation .

Comment: @Chetan both means

Comment: @Chetan if i use background then color on highlight wont work

Comment: but elevation works.

Comment: @Chetan I can't set colour for elevation as i have given in background, its showing error

Comment: What's ur need?

Comment: @Chetan i have a button and image view in relative layout i have made this button transparent using background color of button as a4000000 but on clicking button there is not effect on it, if i haven't given the background color for button then on clicking button color accent reflect on it by this property <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item> so my need is i need this effect on my button at the same time i need my button transparent

Comment: @AlvinVarghese i have a button and image view in relative layout i have made this button transparent using background color of button as a4000000 but on clicking button there is not effect on it, if i haven't given the background color for button then on clicking button color accent reflect on it by this property <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item> so my need is i need this effect on my button at the same time i need my button transparent

Comment: Use selector as bg for button

Comment: @AlvinVarghese didnt get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the solution

1. Create bg_button_selector

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item android:state_pressed="true">
               <shape>
                   <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape>
                   <solid android:color="@color/Normal" />

               </shape>
           </item>

       </selector>
   ```
2. Create Button

   ```
    <Button
       android:text="OTHERS"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/others_button"
       android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
       android:background="@drawable/bg_button_selector"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:textColor="#ffffff" />
   ```

Comment: Where should i Create bg_button_selector

Comment: in drawable folder

Comment: Kkk let me check

Comment: sir it's ok but it too slow response

Comment: on click it changes color for two second i need just single click spot effect and reverse to normal condition

Comment: yes it works on single click only. Please post your code what you have written?

Comment: On click of button any logic you written?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <scale
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.3"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.3"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
i have added this animation to my mutton but it gets soom and suddently after animation time over it goes back to orginal position can i make it to back position slowly as it zoom in at time i click on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138701/discussion-between-rajasekhar-and-arun-mohan).